# A union of proper filters in a chain is a proper filter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, filters

I was looking into the proof of the Ultrafilter lemma by Zorn's lemma, and I wasn't able to find a sufficient explanation for the following claim:

> If $\mathcal{C}\subseteq P$ is a chain of proper filters, then $F:=\cup \mathcal{C}$ is also a proper filter.

I'm okay with showing that $F$ is a filter, but it's not clear to me why it is proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a filter $\cal F$ is proper if and only if $\varnothing\notin\cal F$.

Now suppose that $\cal F$ is the union of *any* family of filters, $\bigcup\cal C$. If $\varnothing\in\cal F$, then by the definition of $\bigcup\cal C$, there is some $X\in\cal C$ such that $\varnothing\in X$. Therefore $X$ could not have been a proper filter.

Comment: Can this reasoning be extended to work with filters on a general partially ordered sets? Not just the case when the partially ordered set is the power set?

Comment: Well, that depends. On a complete lattice, I think yes, because you have a minimum. In a general partial order, probably not. Look at $\Bbb Z$, every end segment is a filter, and a proper filter at that, but the union of all the end segments is $\Bbb Z$ which is not a proper filter. (Replace end- by initial- if necessary, I could never remember the definition in general posets.)